# PHP preg_match_all failing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to extract ID from a possibly huge text, what did I miss?

```
preg_match_all('/(ID\s\d+)/', "ID 20380843, ID ​20675712", $matches);
print_r( $matches[0] );
```

Only return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID 20380843
)
```

Instead of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID 20380843
    [1] => ID 20675712
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you copy that string from your code? Because there is something sneaky happening.
When I copied the code to my editor, it gave me this for string:

```
"ID 20380843, ID ?20675712"
```

As you can see, there is a questionmark-sign in the 2nd, thus failing your expression :)

Comment: Jebus Christo, you're right!  I have an invisible UTF-8 ghosts in my code.  Thanks sooo much!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't preg_replace_all, it's your source file.  There's an invisible unicode character in the second ID - you can see by copy/pasting it into this [Unicode Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/), you'll see U+200B show up in various forms in the lower boxes:

> Unicode U+hex notation
>   preg_match_all('/(ID\s\d+)/', "ID 20380843, ID **U+200B**^20675712", $matches);

(emphasis mine)

This is the [Unicode Zero-Width Spaaace](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), which is apparently not included in `\s` as PHP's PREG defines it.

Comment: yes, the unicode isn't supposed to be there! That was a leftover character from an invalid UTF-8 content.  Thanks for the detail explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`print_r(matches)` instead of `print_r(matches[0]);`

try

```
preg_match_all('/(ID\s\d+)/', "ID 20380843, ID ​20675712", $matches);
print_r( $matches );
```

Comment: $matches[0] is a list of full pattern matches, per the PHP documentation, which is what OP wants: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: You are both correct. $matches[0] does have the two values in your code, see my answer why the same code fails in his run :)